# Unable to alter width of dropdown element

Tags: html, css, dropdown

My intention is to make a top navigation bar, in which the list item `PROJECTS` is supposed to be a dropdown. So far the dropdown is working, but it takes as much width as the parent element. I want to dissociate the dropdown content from the navigation item without changing formatting properties, such that it occupies just as much space needed by its items and is also positioned right below `PROJECTS`.

My code:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

nav li{
  float: left;
}
nav li a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
}
nav li a:hover:not(.active){
  background-color: #444;
}
nav li a.active{
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 1);
}

main{
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.dropdown_content{
  display: none;
  width: auto;
}
.dropbtn:hover .dropdown_content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#" class="active">Home</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
          <li class="dropbtn">
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
            <div class="dropdown_content">
              <a href="#">HTML</a>
              <a href="#">CSS</a>
              <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
  </body>
```

How the result looks now:[image]

How I want it to look(image edited)

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `position: fixed` and `background-color: #666666` for `dropdown_content`. Like that:

```
.dropdown_content {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #666666;
}
```

This will not break the positioning of the dropdown menu, because the `ul` tag also has a fixed positioning.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
}

nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
}

nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #444;
}

nav li a.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 1);
}

main {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #666666;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropbtn">
                    <a href="#">Projects</a>
                    <div class="dropdown_content">
                        <a href="#">HTML</a>
                        <a href="#">CSS</a>
                        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #444;
}

nav li a.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 1);
}

main {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.dropdown_content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
        <li class="dropbtn">
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
          <div class="dropdown_content">
            <a href="#">HTML</a>
            <a href="#">CSS</a>
            <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>

  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I see that besides adding the absolute positioning to the dropdown, you have also removed `overflow: hidden;` from navigation styling. It would be a help to let me know why

Comment: If you have `overflow: hidden` on the parent the children that are out of it's bounds are hidden.